# How to deploy .env and api_config.properties to Google App engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I m new on java, i'm new on google cloud...so maybe my questions can sound stupid. I tried to find before to ask...but i dont found.

I'm triing to deploy a Java app to Google App engine. After a lot of tries i managed to compile the JAR with maven and deploy it to the cloud. I can see that its working with the logs (gcloud app logs). Now the problems i have are:

-I need to include a few files, configuration files, .env , api_config.properties etc... How can i do it? I tried to use include in the app.yaml but it doesnt find the file (ERROR: gcloud crashed (IncludeFileNotFound)) so i suppose this is not the way.

-I need to connect to a postegre instance. This part i didnt try it for now, so i dont know if i will have problems. As i understand i need to create a vm instance with a postegre sql server running on it (i will use bitnami postgre image) i dont need to open ports as it will be a conection from the inside, i m right?

edit: and now i see that its really not connecting the webserver that my app is creating with the app url. that shows "502 Bad Gateway
nginx" message. I supose its because its listening on port 80 instead of 8080, because its not loading it from the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding accessing files please see the options [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/storage-options).

The most fitting for your use case is probably the [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/using-cloud-storage).

If you want to update the configuration files when you deploy to app engine, i suggest that you create some deployment method that will include uploading the configuration files to Cloud Storage if they need to be updated.

Comment: wow, that's seems complicated, but seems to be what I am searching, thanks! and the postegre SQL question is answered too, thanks!

Comment: I mark these answer as the solution because it is what i was searching for: upload static files. But after reading the documentation i did what olivier tells, and used env_variables it seemed easier.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.yaml, you may define an [env_variables](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/config/appref) section. This is in my opinion the best way to store configuration data, sensitive or not.

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer! but I need to upload files. the app is already coded and it's loading all the configs from these files, it's server side, so I don't think it's a security problem. and in addition I need some other files for the http server part (HTML and CSS files)